# Why does a variable only pass the first value of a for loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The value of ident changes at the first comment like it should, but at the second comment (in the jQuery function) ident always displays the value stored at `arr[0]['ident']`.

Code:

```
for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    var ident = arr[i]['ident'];
    console.log(ident+' ');
    $(document).on('click','#'+ident, function() {
        console.log('over'+ident+' ');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has function scope, not block scope. You can use `var ident` inside the loop, but that doesn't mean you're actually creating a new variable `ident`; there will only be one `ident` inside your function. All functions created/bound inside of your loop share the same reference to that single `ident` variable.

By the time any of your event handlers run, `ident` has been repeated reset to a new value, until the final iteration when it will be set to `arr[arr.length - 1]['ident']`. Every event handling function will have that same value for `ident`, because they all share a reference to the same `ident` variable.

To fix this, you need to pass each function its own variable to close over, typically done with an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    (function (ident) {
      console.log(ident+' ');
      $(document).on('click','#'+ident, function() {
          console.log('over'+ident+' ');
      });
    })(arr[i]['ident']);
}
```

Comment: explain little bit more?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to find an appropriate duplicate to close this

Comment: @meagar I couldn't find one. And yes, please explain. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ChrisRockGM See my update, and also https://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript+variable+loop&oq=javascript+variable+loop&aqs=chrome..69i57.5816j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+variable+loop+always+last

Comment: Okay, but how do I fix it?

Comment: @meagar I get how the second one works but still not getting why the first one doesn't!

Comment: @halkujabra You'll have to be more specific

Comment: for loop doesn't create a scope in javascript. So, there is only one ident variable created and not one per iteration.